# Redux.js and data with relations

Tags: javascript, relational-database, redux, immutable.js

Imagine that you develop some react-redux application (with global immuatable tree-state). And some data have some rules-relations in different tree-branches, like SQL relations between tables.

I.e. if you are working on some company's todos list, each todo has relation(many-to-one) with concrete user. And if you add some new user, you should add empty todo list (to other branch in the state). Or delete user means that you should re-assign user's todos to some (default admin) user.

You can hardcode this relation directly to source code. And it is good and works OK. 
But imagine that you have got million small relations for data like this. It will be good that some small "automatic" operations/checks (for support/guard relations) performs automatically according to rules.

May be existed some common approach/library/experience to do it via some set of rules: like triggers in SQL:

`on add new user => add new empty todos`

`on user delete => reassign todos to default user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions here. I don't think that you should aim to have this kind of functionality in a redux application, so my first example is not quite what you're looking for but I think is more conical.  The second example adopts a DB/orm pattern, which may work fine, but is not conical, and requires

These could be trivially added safely with vanilla redux and `redux-thunk`. Redux thunk basically allows you to dispatch a single action that its self dispatches multiple other actions--so when you trigger `CREATE_USER`, just do something along the lines of triggering `CREATE_EMPTY_TODO`, `CREATE_USER`, and `ASSIGN_TODO` in the `createUser` action. For deleting users, `REASSIGN_USER_TODOS` and then `DELETE_USER`.

For the examples you provide, here are examples:

```
function createTodoList(todos = []) {
  return dispatch => {
    return API.createTodoList(todos)
      .then(res => { // res = { id: 15543, todos: [] }
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_TODO_LIST_SUCCESS', res });
        return res;
      });
  }
}

function createUser (userObj) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(createTodoList())
      .then(todoListObj => {
        API.createUser(Object.assign(userObj, { todoLists: [ todoListObj.id ] }))
          .then(res => { // res = { id: 234234, name: userObj.name, todoLists: [ 15534 ]}
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_USER_SUCCESS', payload: res });
            return res;
          })
      })
      .catch(err => console.warn('Could not create user because there was an error creating todo list'));

  }
}
```

Deleteing, sans async stuff.

```
function deleteUser (userID) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'REASSIGN_USER_TODOS',
      payload: {
        fromUser: userID,
        toUser: getState().application.defaultReassignUser
      });

    dispatch({
      type: 'DELETE_USER',
      payload: { userID }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem with this method, as mentioned in the comments, is that a new developer might come onto the project without knowing what actions already exist, and then create their own version of `createUser` which doesn't know to create todos. While you can never completely take away their ability to write bad code, you can try to be more defensive by making your actions more structured. For example, if your actions look like this:

```
const createUserAction = {
  type: 'CREATE',
  domain: 'USERS',
  payload: userProperies
}
```

you can have a reducer structured like this

```
function createUserTrigger (state, userProperies) {
  return {
    ...state,
    todoLists: {
      ...state.todoLists,
      [userProperies.id]: []
    }
  }
}

const triggers = {
  [CREATE]: {
    [USERS]: createUserTrigger
  }
}

function rootReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, domain, payload } = action;
  let result = state;

  switch (type) {
    case CREATE:
      result = {
        ...state,
        [domain]: {
          ...state[domain],
          [payload.id]: payload
        }
      };
      break;
    case DELETE:
      delete state[domain][payload.id];
      result = { ...state };
      break;
    case UPDATE:
      result = {
        ...state,
        [domain]: {
          ...state[domain],
          [payload.id]: _.merge(state[domain][payload.id], payload)
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.warn('invalid action type');
      return state;
  }

  return triggers[type][domain] ? triggers[type][domain](result, payload) : result;
}
```

In this case, you're basically forcing all developers to use a very limited possible set of action types. Its very rigid and I don't really recommend it, but I think it does what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Am I right that you suggest to split big handling function to some small, and call it one-by-one. I understand and it works OK. But I asking in my question something like trigger. I.e. whenever some new value will be added to some place in the tree (of application state) (i.e. to the user list) do some specific operation like `CREATE_EMPTY_TODO`. it seems like to add it to the "master reducer", i.e. execute it after each tree change, but it could be very expensive (like check data relations for long user list).

Comment: So you're concerned about having actions be checked against all reducers for their matches? For example, you don't want the entire `rootReducer` to look at all handlers for those matching `CREATE_EMPTY_TODO`? Also, the idea of a 'trigger' outside of your action creator is identical to my example--the implemention is effectively the same, but maybe is handled in middleware. There is no way to update state based on *how* a reducer changed; Only actions cant initiate state change. Any other source of state change is an anti-pattern in redux.

Comment: Yes I thought about some language like SQL (and some memory DB), for support data relationship for application state. let's imagine that someone else who don't know about relation between user and todos is implementing some new reducer (like import users from file). And he will manipulate application state "directly" (without using `createUser` action). So he forget to add empty todos. With some data-relations-oriented store, that problems with data will fix automatically( according relations rules)....

Comment: I think that this is an unfortunate scenario, and I think that its easy to fix, but agree that its possible if the developer is inexperienced. I have an idea that I'll try to flesh out in the above example...